# How to highlight the rows relating to the "Count Of" in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I have a table with values, and next to it a pivot table showing count of certain fields (same sheet). 
I want to be able to click the field or count value on the pivot table (either number or field name) and the associated rows in the table will be highlighted/selected.

E.g. the table has fruit types, the pivot table says "Apple | 3", "Orange | 2" etc, when i click either "Apple" or "3" i want the apple rows of the table to highlight or become selected, so its easier to see those fields....

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. But double clicking on an item in a pivot table will put you in a new sheet with all the data that made up that item.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting can be done with Conditional Formatting that uses a formula rule.  If cell E1 contains the word "Apple", select column A and apply the a conditional formatting rule with the formula:

```
=$A1=$E$1
```

When you change the value in cell E1, different cells will be highlighted. To tie cell E1 to whatever cell you click in the pivot table, you would need VBA.